# Are Mod of Rings are the same to Quotient Groups?

Tags: ring-theory

---

I found they sometimes are both written in $A/N$ pronounced $(A \bmod N)$

A remainder ring? a quotient group?

what's the difference?

Are there any conventional problems in notations?

Comment: Look up "quotient group" and "quotient ring" to see for yourself.

Comment: @annon ok, good to know the word `quotient ring`. I like asking in SE and one of my purpose is forcing myself writing in English.

Comment: Yes. It is the quotient by that subgroup given the structure of the ring.

Comment: @HyperGroups, it is very good to want to write in English, but usually you should not ask questions which are answered by standard sources like Wikipedia!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez ok, learned that, sometimes I'm daunting at the large material in Wikipedia, of course they are so good. If I've read some materials like Wikipedia, and cannot understand clearly, is that good to ask here for some explanation?

Comment: Yes, indeed, HyperGroups: that's a fine approach...and when you do post here, after checking out Wikipedia, *mention* that you read Wiki...but don't understand ....(fill in the blank).

Comment: @HyperGroups: I don't know if this is still relevant to you, but you may consider using [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

$A/N$ isn't necessarily a quotient ring: just as with groups, the notation $\,A/N\,$ denotes the set of *cosets* of $\,N\,$ in $\,A.\,$ When $N$ is *normal* in group $A$, we have that $\,A/N\,$ is a **quotient group** (aka "factor group"). Similarly, when $N = I$ is an *ideal* in ring $A$, we have that $\,A/N\,$ a **quotient ring**.:

> In ring theory, a branch of abstract algebra, a **[quotient ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring)**, also known as factor ring or residue class ring, is a construction quite similar to the factor [quotient] groups of group theory and the quotient spaces of linear algebra. One starts with a ring $R$ and a two-sided ideal $I$ in $R$, and constructs a new ring, the quotient ring $R/I$, essentially by requiring that all elements of $I$ be zero in $R$. Intuitively, the quotient ring $R/I$ is a "simplified version" of $R$ where the elements of $I$ are "ignored".

---

See also this earlier post: [What is a quotient ring and cosets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23655/what-is-a-quotient-ring-and-cosets). You may find the question and the accepted answer to be very helpful, too.

Comment: of course helpful, need time to digest :)

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, $A/N$ means the set of cosets of $N$ in $A$, endowed with binary operation(s) defined by their action on coset representatives.