# Understanding the notation $\mathbb Z_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation

Let $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$ be the ring of all polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. List the elements of the field $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]/〈x^2+x+1〉$, and make an addition and multiplication table for the field.

I'm don't really understand what this notation means,$\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]/〈x^2+x+1〉$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's a quotient ring: see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23655/what-is-a-quotient-ring-and-cosets).

Comment: So its a quotient ring. Ok, so is this a correct equivalency? $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\left \langle x^2+x+1 \right \rangle=\left \{ ax+b+\left \langle x^2+x+1 \right \rangle \right \}$ Where do I go from here?

Comment: How many cosets can you possibly have?

Comment: In this case would the number of cosets be elements on the table or elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\left \langle x^2+x+1 \right \rangle $

Comment: Each coset contains a representative that is remainder of a polynomial after dividing $x^2+x+1$. How many possible remainders are there? Note that the remainder must be of smaller degree than $x^2+x+1$.

Comment: $4$ or so? $0,1,x,x+1$?

Comment: Yup so now you can construct your tables using these representatives :D

Comment: And if a polynomial has degree $\ge 2$, by polynomial division, it is a representative of one of the $4$ cosets that we already know.

Comment: @CodyS Next time, use a more useful title. People are more likely to look at a title that gives them some idea of what they are about to answer. Nobody cares to look at titles like "random abstract algebra question help!" I also picked some more useful tags for you.

Answer (score 0):

To try to cover all the bases:

$\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$ is the polynomial ring with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$, the field of two elements.

$\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]$.

$\mathbb{Z}_2 [x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ is the quotient ring with respect to this ideal. That is, it is the set of cosets of the equivalence relation $x\sim y \iff x-y\in \langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ with the natural ring structure.

Intuitively, in this quotient every element of $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ is equivalent to some polynomial of degree $1$ or less.